# Custom home page with iWeb

Tags: html, iweb, mobileme

How can I create a custom 'skin-style' homepage for a website published in iWeb?

The current root URL mydomain.com redirects to mydomain.com/myiWebsite/welcome.html. I want to create a new homepage at the root URL, which has links to the other published pages on the site. I guess this will mean telling iWeb to stop redirecting from the root?

Comment: The solution is simply to modify the index.html file that sits above the iWeb publishing folder on the server, removing the redirect header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to the actual publishing directory on the server? is the server your computer or do you actually host these files somewhere else? Does iWeb just upload the files you create in iWeb to the server you specify?

Most likely, iWeb has created an `index.html` file at `mydomain.com` that has an auto-redirect header in it. It is either that, or there is a server-level (`.htaccess`) config file that is telling all requests to `mydomain.com` to go to the welcome page.

In either situation, telling the server/html page to do something else probably won't fix the problem if you continue to use iWeb as your method of publishing to the server, since iWeb expects your pages to behave the way iWeb sets them up to behave. Changing one thing could very easily break all of the other parts of your pages iWeb has created.

I hate to be the guy that says "You should just do it all from scratch and be hardcore" but unless iWeb has a preference for making the change within iWeb, you probably have to choose between iWeb and how it does things or something else entirely.

Comment: Thanks Anthony - in a perfect world I would do just as you suggest. Useful advice in any case.